# Содержит ли предложение причину того, о чем говорится в предложении?

Tags: смысл

> *1) Но вот что я замечал, Ольга Олеговна, он слишком часто употреблял
> слова "ребята сказали., все говорят... все так делают". 2) Все носят
> длинные волосы на загривке - и мне надо, все употребляют словечко
> "пахан" вместо "отец" - и я это делаю, все берут призы по спортивным
> соревнованиям - и мне не след отставать, покажу, что не хуже других,
> волю проявлю, настойчивость.*

**Содержит ли предложение 2 причину, о чем говорится в предложении 1?**

**Содержит ли предложение 1 причину, о чем говорится в предложении 2?**

Я считаю, что причину достаточно сложно выделить и есть ли она - решать автору, но всё же можете накинуть, пожалуйста, варианты, а могут ли данные предложения быть причинными и почему? Спасибо

Comment: Это слишком сложные предложения, в них трудно разобраться. Вот если было бы что-то попроще. 1. Все так делают (носят, берут итд). 2. Все носят и (поэтому) я буду. PS Слово поэтому выражает причину в русском языке

Comment: @user190920 "поэтому я буду" что?) вы не закончили мысль

Comment: Предложение "Все носят и я буду." в разговорном языке абсолютно нормальное. В теории согласен надо бы добавить "носить".

Answer (score 4):

Мне кажется, что предложение 2 указывает **на причину** предложения 1, а не наоборот. Оба предложения **раскрывают одну тему**, но в предложении 2 указана возможная причина.

**Какая?** Она в словах "***покажу, что не хуже других***". Возможно, раньше (в детстве, например) у него был какой-то недостаток (внешность, физическое развитие, бедность родителей и т.д.), и он ощущал себя хуже других. Или он был не хуже, а его таким считали. И вот теперь ему **надо доказать себе и другим**: нет, он не хуже.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

Наверное, с учетом ВСЕХ мнений, можно сказать так. Причина указана в предложении 2, это **желание вписаться в коллектив**: быть как все, говорить как все, быть не хуже других. В предложение 1 назван частотный оборот его речи "***как все,***" а почему он так говорит? Предложение 2 отвечает на этот вопрос.

А вот откуда у него такое желание, мы не знаем. Эта тема в данном фрагменте текста не раскрыта – возможно, об этом говорится где-то раньше.

Comment: Насколько понимаю, он делает это ради того, чтобы быть как все, ибо это проще и так вписываешься в коллектив. В таком случае причина  предложение будет содержать?

Comment: Ищет в жизни простые пути, чтобы чувствовать себя защищенным? А откуда у него такое  желание? Если это не указать, то причина не будет найдена, это только тема обоих предложений. Но давайте подождем другие ответы-мнения.

Comment: Спойлер: ФИПИ посчитал, что там причины нет

Answer (score 2):

Если хотите узнать ответ, а не читать внутренний монолог, который привел меня к нему то лучше читайте сразу со слова **КОНЕЦ**. Короче, советую не читать все до слова **Самый конец**.

Это не называется причиной, *это*(по началу я подумал, что имеется ввиду фраза "ребята сказали..." - повторил вслед за Sharon)  называется посылкой. Причина это другое.

["Посылка, в широком смысле — то, на основании чего делается вывод или умозаключение."](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/enc_philosophy/4695/%D0%9F%D0%9E%D0%A1%D0%AB%D0%9B%D0%9A%D0%90)

Предложение 1 содержит посылку на основании которой можно сделать умозаключения в предложении 2.

То есть посылка это указатель: найди красный цвет -> красный цвет в этом предложении. Никаких причин для существования посылки не нужно, кроме мемичной ассоциации. То есть в фразе номер 1 "я" повторяет за кем-то, обращаясь к Ольге Олеговне, что мол "кто-то третий слишком часто говорит, что"ребята сказали, все говорят...". Ох, да тут целая курьерская служба - посылка в посылке, цикл посылок, так как "я" тоже повторил это за кем-то...

А еще тут один хитрый психологический момент, так как посылка дается не просто как утверждение, а утверждение сказанное в диалоге третьих, по отношению к читателю, лиц, это делает мем-утверждение более убедительным, то есть читатель воспринимает это как некую мудрость, которую в итоге будет использовать в качестве веского аргумента в последующих дискуссиях. То есть мемичность посылок дело весьма заразительное.

Но о причине подобного поведения ни в первом, ни во втором предложении ни слова. Хотя посылка дает оценку - повторять за другими плохо.

*Ох, тут еще нужно сказать, одну важную вещь, так что придется позанудствовать еще. Дело в том, что я тут уже писал, но слово мораль имеет только положительное значение. Мораль - это то, как нужно поступать, поступать хорошо. Но по ряду причин, слово мораль, читать морали приобрело значение некого учения, как делать не надо. Хотя по логике это уже "учение аморальное", или "об аморальности". Так вот, по какой-то причине, мораль очень часто любят давать в негативной форме мем-посылок: повторять за другими ребятами плохое - плохо. Однако почему плохо - не скажут, то есть разговора о причине такого повторения, почему это плохо - речи не будет. но почему-то считается, что если подросток смог повторить эту глупость (найти посылку) - то уже достижение. Потому что главное, это как в мультике Хитрука "Икар и Мудрецы": "квон лицет йови, нон лицет бови" - там Икар слушал слушал, как школота повторяет мемы-посылки, а потому полетел всем наперекор. Не знаю, может в итоге все эти псевдоистины и псевдопричины заставляют искать истинные причины, уходя от мем-посылок? Но там хотя бы логика была. А тут скорее подростки поступят наоборот, хотя как, не понятно. В общем методика древняя, но абсолютно дурная.*

Причина же - это вообще сложное понятие, но фундаментальное. Причина - это то, что формирует вопрос, который можно задать. То есть вопрос - это некое указание на причину. Но не каждый вопрос, а вопросы класса Почему?(основной причинный вопрос) и реже Когда?, Где?, Что? и тп. - могут быть причинными... А вот вопросы Как?, Какой?, Каким образом? и тд. - не являются причинными.

Например:

-Почему Ольга Ольговна заговорила о том, что "ребята делают..."?

-Потому что она учит ребят, заставляет задуматься... Причина - желание научить.

-Где она это сделала?

-В школе. В школе учат детей(через вопрос почему?), поэтому она учила. Причина - потому что она работает за зп учителем в школе и это входит в её обязанности...

Ну и тд.

С помощью причины можно копать вглубь сути чего-то, искать эту суть, а с помощью посылки - можно приходить к логическому выводу.

**Не нужно путать поиск решения, ход решение, который начинается с постановки проблемы - все на основании причины,  с результатом решения - ответом, определенным посылкой.**

И, по-другому, это называется сократовским методом, а в вульгарном варианте -  софистикой, когда путем задания заранее сформированной цепочки вопросов содержащих ответы Да/Нет можно человека привести к противоречивым, но вроде бы логичным, выводам. Причинность (основа критического мышления) - это умение формировать вопросы, а не умение выстраивать ассоциативные ряды из посылок, давая заведомо "верные", ожидаемые ответы. Для последнего особого умения не надо, и ответ всегда можно списать из интернета.

Да, ну и слова "поэтому", "потому что" и похожие - могут указывать, что причина где-то там была или подразумевается, что это не просто посылка, а есть основания для посылки - это верно. Однако, все эти слова есть реверсные конструкции от причинного вопроса "Почему?".

В общем я был невнимателен, запутался и всех запутал. Надо исправлять ситуацию)

Но не в том что написал, а в выборе посылок.

Итак смотрим, на первое предложение и оно действительно имеет не совсем причину, но связанное с ней:

"я замели что" или "что я заметил" - это и есть причина.

"я заметил, что в **он часто употреблял**" одни и те же посылки, - причинная аргументация.

Если мы посмотрим на **2**, то там действительно перечисление с повторением "как они так и я".

То есть причина может указывать на некоторую закономерность - в данном случае повторение языковых конструкций.

И из **2** мы действительно можем заметить "что...", то есть аргументацию.

Однако, все-таки неверно, назвать аргументацию причиной, так как причина - это внимательность, что ли, то что я заметил повторение.

Причина - явление, непосредственно обусловливающее, порождающее др. явление (следствие). Философская энциклопедия 60-70 годов.

Но вот что пишут в современных изданиях:

Причина(cause) - то, без чего не было бы другого – следствия (см. Каузальность). Новый *философский словарь за 2010 год.* Я не знаю кто его авторы, но вот что они пишут далее: Первоначально причина понимается как **предмет**...

И тут у меня появилась догадка, быть может то, что создатели словаря понимают как причину-предмет(а не явление) это и есть то, что я ранее назвал "причинным аргументом". Логика такая, что повторяемость некой мемичной конструкции("все говорят"), стала причиной того, что "я" её заметил и повторил. Прекрасно... прямо причина и следствие, а то что "я" в этот момент думал о чем-то - не важно.

Тут правда есть ряд противоречий, ведь даже википедия на вопрос о cause дает следующее "is influence by which one event, process, state, or object" - вызванное событием, процессом, состоянием или объектом (а не предметом!). Вот честно, я не знаю, какие буратины писали эти новые словари, но это не русский, и даже не английский, это рунглиш, когда словам приписывают несуществующие значение ногой, аргументируя их связью с неким отлатинским понятием.

**Конец.**

И тут все начинает приобретать смысл! То есть нас просят найти не причину, которая причина, а "причину" которая значит "cause", которая не cause, короче нужно угадать, что авторы имеют ввиду. А ввиду они имеют, что внимание "я", когда он слушал другого, привлекла повторяющаяся конструкция "все говорят и я буду", после чего он решил её повторить, сказав об этом Ольге Ольговне. То есть внимательность "я" - это вызванный "*эффект*", а "*причина*", которая вызвала его - повторение однотипной фразы. И мы можем действительно наблюдать *это* повторение в 2.

Ура, я решил(казалось бы), 1 действительно содержит "*причину*", которая есть и в 2. Хотя конечно, любому адекватному человеку понятно, что нужно быть биороботом, чтобы считать свою внимательность эффектом возникающим от внешнего фактора.

Может быть это какой-то вопрос из теста Тьюринга - типа не робот ли ты?

**почти конец**

Но да, действительно, это же ЕГЭ, тут нужно ответить четко, без вот этих всех рассуждений.

Итак, представим что у нас вообще нет слова "причина", а есть указание на некоторую логическую связку, где из А следует-> B. Причем, как указала Sharon, что-то есть в одном, но нет в другом. И кроме того формулировка выглядит как "причина, о которой говорится" - то есть в этом предложении говорится об этом.

Очевидно, речь идет о ключевой фразе "он слишком часто повторял" - это как раз оговаривание "причины", а "причина" находится в другом предложении, в виде ряда повторений которые имеют место быть - да, "он" действительно повторяет. То есть в высказывании 1 говорится о том, что имело место быть фактически в высказывании 2, но о чем в высказывании 2 повествования не шло, а причина - это некий факт вырванный из контекста. Ну и проверяя себя видим схемку 2->1, из фактического повторения в 2 следует упоминания о повторении в 1.

Самое сложно для меня было абстрагироваться от значения слова "причина".

**Самый конец.**

"2 содержит причину, о которой говорится в 1".

**Из всего этого можно вывести локальное правило(алгоритм): нужно искать  "что" - это указание, но не на "причину", а ее "эффект". Заметил, что - Б, а сама "причина"-А другом предложении, видимо так это нужно решать.**

Или еще проще: какое предложение содержит А, о чем говорится в другом предложении? Предложение 2 содержит А (части фраз), о которой говорится в 1 предложении.

Всё

Comment: Ого. Спасибо за такой развернутый комментарий и рассуждения! 
*Это текст из ЕГЭ... А составители... я сомневаюсь, что они столько же рассуждали, сколько вы, чтобы составить такое задание*

Comment: @Буратино Действительно, очень интересные у вас рассуждения. Но помогите, пожалуйста, найти фразу, по которой можно различить две части текста. Нужно что-то очевидное, что есть в одном случае и чего нет в другом. Может быть, это поможет обозначить "причину" в таком плане, как ее понимают составители задания. Ведь школьники должны решить задание быстро и коротко записать ответ.

Comment: @Sharon Ох, похоже нужно переписать весь этот бред) "он слишком часто повторял" - это фраза ключевая. А повторение действительно имеет место быть во 2. Так что "причина" во 2 - повторение, а в 1, что "я" это повторение заметил. То есть причина того, что "я" обратился к Ольге Ольговне была, что он заметил повторение, которое фактически, но было, хотя не было обозначено, во втором предложении. 2 содержит "причину" 1. Возможно, "я замечал" - можно расценить, как указание на "причину" во 2. Или "что" - это тут указание на эффект, значит "причина" в другом предложении.

Comment: @Мал очевидно, я бы никогда не сдал ЕГЭ)

Comment: @Буратино *приводишь такие огромные, развернутые рассуждения, а потом оказывается, что и составители даже не думали об этом*

Comment: Я тоже... У них там свои правила  (даже в грамматике) и свои правильные ответы. Их нужно угадать :)

Comment: @Мал я честно, не знаю о чем они думают, я же с ними не знаком, поэтому приходится придумывать из коллективный образ, метод как видишь дурацкий и очень затратный, придумать причину того, о чем говорится в задании ЕГЭ), без конкретной информации, а только по косвенным намекам. А если по-простому, нужно искать указание "что" - это указание но не на "причину", а ее "эффект". Заметил что - Б, а причина другом, видимо так это нужно решать. Такую логику решения кто-то туда закладывал. Чем проще объяснение тем ближе к правильному решению ЕГЭ, мне так кажется)

Comment: @Sharon Задача ЕГЭ - не в том, чтобы проверить уровень понимания предмета, а править "знания", знания могут быть основаны на неких правилах, которые одной части сообщаются и дети "натаскиваются" на их применение, а другая часть, не зная правила, должна чудом угадать с вероятностью 0.5 или меньше, то есть среднестатистически решить только половину заданий. Так происходит отсев по ЕГЭ, в этом нет смысла, в этом есть зания "простых" правил и вероятностная статистика.